# How to click a image form my dialog insert to ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, ckeditor

I using ckeditor to post news and article in my website

I create a plugin function on post page (eg. post_news.php)

that plugin will foreach many images in a JQ dialog.

I want click one image will insert a image to ckeditor mouse cursor postion

< img src"abc.png">

Q1. How to... click a image in a dialog(not ck plugin) to insert a image html code to ckeditor mouse cursor postion

Q2. can I complete this action in the WYSIWYG mode?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`editor.insertHtml( string )`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml) to insert HTML at the position of the caret:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml( '<img src="...">' );
```

And this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html) is where you'll find how to get the outer HTML of your image.

Comment: like that?<img src="abc.com" onclick="insertatcursor()" />
<script>
    function insertatcursor() {
            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHTML('<a href="test.html">test</a>');
    }
</script>  but not work :(